# 404 error when Uploading CI to Server

Tags: codeigniter

I got an error when hosting my CI project, it success in localhost. I have change my 
old
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8000/myweb'; in config.php to
new
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myweb.com';

.htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this is the error :
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mod_rewrite is enabled, in case of Apache server!

To enable mod_rewrite:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then:

```
service apache2 restart
```

In application/config/config.php set:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess exemple:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Solved, that's not my problem. Thanks for answer

Comment: What was it the problem?

Comment: the capital letter